# Image Smoothing using map-reduce

Tags: image-processing, mapreduce

I have an image whose RGB values for each pixel is stored in a 2-D array. Assuming I want to apply, a basic 3X3 averaging algorithm for smoothing the image. How can I implement such an algorithm using map-reduce paradigm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: map-reduce would be helpful if the algorithm required "reduction" to join results of sub-tasks.  In this case, the smoothing operation is local, and no combination other than placement of result pixels is needed.   The problem is inherently separable, and can be done in parallel.

Comment: @Photon - Thanks for the feedback. Yes, doing it in parallel is good. But, i wanted to do it by map-reduce.

Answer (score 1):

This took me a while to think in map reduce paradigm but anyways here it is -

**Map Task**

Input - (x-coordinate,y-coordinate,RGB value)

Output - 9 tuples which are these {(x,y,RGB),(x-1,y,RGB),(x-1,y-1,RGB),(x,y-1,RGB),(x+1,y-1,RGB),(x+1,y,RGB),(x-1,y+1,RGB),(x,y+1,RGB),(x+1,y+1,RGB)}

**Reduce Task**

The framework will sort all these tuples based on the keys(x-coordinate,y-coordinate) and rearrange them.So now for each pixel you have 9 RGB values of it's neighboring pixels. We simply average them in the reduce task and output a tuple ----> (x,y,avg_RGB)

So, basically instead of each pixel telling the RGB values of all its neighboring pixels for itself, it broadcasts it's own RGB value as pixel value of it's neighbors.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.